# after implementing a navigation drawer, fullscreen doesn't work properly anymore

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, fullscreen, navigationbar

i have added a navigation drawer to an activity and now the space where normaly the navigation bar is set (in my case it should be hidden by a fullscreen call) is occupied by a blank space. without the navigation drawer the activity works just fine, fullscreen and no blank space. i also recognized that it works fine on devices with hardwarebuttons, there is no blankspace, like on a google pixel i.e.

Layout XMLs:

Activity xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/webViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_panel">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_to_the_left"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:alpha="0.2"
                android:background="@drawable/arrowcircle"
                tools:mockup_opacity="50%" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_Decision1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorDecision1"
                android:text="@string/action_decision1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceInverse" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_Decision2"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorDecision2"
                android:text="@string/action_decision2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceInverse" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_Decision3"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorDecision3"
                android:text="@string/action_decision3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceInverse" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_to_the_right"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:alpha="0.2"
                android:background="@drawable/arrowcircle"
                android:rotation="180" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_text_act" />
```

following are the xml-files from the AS template fro navigation drawer
app_bar_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.max.mybai.controller.MbaiStartActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

content_main.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.max.mybai.controller.MbaiStartActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
```

nav_header_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Menu"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Code from the Activity (which i took from the AS template for navigation drawer) except the fullscreen()

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_save_story) {

        // Save current reading progress to Shared Preferences
        ...
        Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(), "Geschichte wurde gespeichert", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}




    public void FullScreencall() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if (!(ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey())) {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to set android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in relativelayout in Activity xml:

Comment: was not quite the right solution but you put me in the right direction, got it fixed by deleting android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from all Layouts. THX